# Dynamic Programming Algorithm: Maximum sum of coins (less or equal to k)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a list of n coin values and a sum k, find the maximum possible sum which is less or equal to k. Each coin can be used as many times as necessary. If no coins are chosen 0 is considered maximum.
I tried solving this problem and I know that this is dynamic programming but i can't solve this in less than O(n^2).
What would be the algorithm for this problem?

Comment: I think you can use the same `coin change` algorithm. But that would be O(nk)

Comment: you cannot solve it in O(n^2) unless P=NP (most likely P!=NP), since this is the subset sum problem, which is NP Complete. DP solution for integers offers psedo-polynomial O(nk)

Comment: Try to frame the problem as "Let's define f(___) to be the maximum possible sum obeying the restrictions ___".  What could you replace the ___s with?  (The two ___s could be different here.)

Comment: @amit: It's related, but is it really the same?  It's easy to convert this problem to subset sum -- just add RoundUp(k/value[i]) copies of each coin i -- but it's not obvious how to go in the other direction, i.e. how to represent a *finite* number of copies of some number in a subset sum problem inside this problem.

Comment: @j_random_hacker `Given a list of n coin values and a sum k, find the maximum possible sum which is less or equal to k. ` this is exactly the *optimization problem* of subset sum. Minor difference is you can chose each element multiple times,  which does not make the problem any easier/harder.

Comment: @amit: You claim that allowing any number of copies doesn't make it easier/harder, but I think it makes the problem easier: the valid solutions to subset sum form a subset of the valid solutions to this problem.  There might well be a reduction *from* SS *to* this problem, but I'd need to see it before I accept that they're equivalently difficult problems.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Given a set `S={x1,x2,...,xn}` you can create a set `S'={x1_1,x1_2,...,x1_n, x2_1,x2_2,...,x2_n,...,xn_1,xn_2,...,xn_n}`. This list is of size `O(n^2)`, and thus still polynomial in the original input size, apply the 0-1 subset sum algorithm, and the solution to it is the solution to the "modified" subset sum.

Comment: @amit: I appreciate the effort and don't mean to nitpick, but as I see it, where you say "apply the 0-1 subset sum algorithm", you need to instead say "apply the OP's max-sum-of-coins algorithm" for this to be a reduction.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Sorry, babies cried, so I release half baked comment. Anyway, you are not nitpicking, you are correct - but the problem is still NP-Complete, it is basically a true/false variant of [change-making problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem). The change making is giving you infinity for a sum you cannot create, so you are looking for the largest sum lower than `k` that is not `infinity`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Also, the feasibility problem from change making is proven to be NP-Hard by Lueker, 1975 in `Two NP-complete problems in nonnegative integer programming` (didn't find the article itself, but found two references for this claim: [\[1\]](http://www.or.deis.unibo.it/kp/Chapter5.pdf), [\[2\]](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~kozen/papers/change.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

you cannot solve it in O(n^2) unless P=NP (most likely P!=NP), since this is the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is [NP Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete). [DP solution for integers offers psedo-polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) `O(nk)` time, and is probably your best bet.

In your case, you can chose an element more than once, so the recursive formulas will be:

```
D(0,i) = true
D(x,0) = false   x!=0
D(x,i) = D(x-coin[i],i) OR D(x,i-1)
                     ^
          note i and not (i-1) here
```

You need to find the highest `x` smaller than `k` such that `D(x,n) = true`, which is fairly easy - if you construct a 2D table of size (k+1)*(n+1) - you need to find the rightest column (let it be `x`) such that `D[x][n] = true`, which is fairly easy to find in a single path on the last line.

Comment: One question: does D(x,i) represent the true/false value of the statement: can sum x be achieved from i coins?

Comment: @user3245855 D(x,i) represents the true/false value of the statement: can sum x be achieved from coins `{c1,c2,...,ci}`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define INT_MAX 99999999
using namespace std;
int compare(const void *a,const void *b)
{
    return *(int*)a-*(int*)b;
}

struct res
{
    bool yes;
    int count;
};
struct res *t=new struct res [2000001];
//t=new struct res [1000001];
int fun(int arr[],int n,int k)
{
    int max=arr[n-1]*k;
    t[0].yes=true;
    t[0].count=0;
    int f;
    for(int i=1;i<max;i++)
    {
        t[i].yes=false;
        t[i].count=INT_MAX;
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            int val=arr[j];
            int cnt=1;
            f=0;
            while(val<=i && cnt<=k)
            {
                if(t[i-val].yes==true)
                {
                    t[i].yes=true;
                    t[i].count=min(t[i].count,cnt+t[i-val].count);
                    break;
                }
                val+=arr[i];
                cnt++;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=1;i<max;i++)
    {
        if(t[i].count>k)
            return i-1;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int t,k,n;
    int arr[50];
    cin>>t;
    int x=1;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>k>>n;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>arr[i];
        qsort(arr,n,sizeof(int),compare);
        cout<<"Case #"<<x<<endl<<fun(arr,n,k)<<endl;
        x++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Any explanation would be helpful.